# Using ArcPy to rename MXD layers?

Tags: arcpy, layers, mxd, error-000840

I have a MXD with some layers that have parentheses in them. I'd like to rename them via script.

Is this a valid approach?

```
import re
map = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map)
for layer in layers:
    if re.search("[()]", layer.name):
        newName = re.sub("[()]", "", layer.name)
        arcpy.Rename_management(layer, newName)
```

`Rename_management` is giving me an error:

> Runtime error : ERROR 000840:
>   The value is not a Data Element.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because [arcpy.Rename_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000056000000) does not work on a map layer object - it works on objects on the disk.

Instead try:

```
layer.name = newName
```

`layer.name` is a read/write attribute of the [arcpy.mapping.Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) class.